# Azure function Skype bot output binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, skype-bots

I'm building a bot which should receive message from azure function and display that message to the user.

In [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) there is the documentation for bindings of all azure services, but the bot output binding isn't documented.

I know that the output binding can be created setting the configuration from `bindings.json` and using parameter `out BotMessage message` in the function as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure-bot-service-template-proactive), but this is the approach when developing functions with C# scripts. Instead I'm using .NET class libraries.

How can I achieve the ouput binding using .NET class libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the following NuGet package : `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.BotFramework` (check `Include prerelease` if you don't see it in Visual Studio 2017).

Then you should be able to mark your output parameter with corresponding binding attribute:

```cs
[Bot(BotId = "...")] out BotMessage message
```

Comment: Quick response! Where did you find documentation for this package? I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Me neither, just found the package itself

Comment: Very useful. Thank you

Comment: @Mikhail, Just to let you know, this package is ok with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions <= 1.0.11`. I just tried with newest version and it is not working anymore